# C# do some actions after that keep active to catch process start and end

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've written a C# Console application which does some actions and after that i need to keep it active to catch a secondary program start and closing.

The set-up should look like this:

---

**Run once**

Action 1

Action 2

Action 3

**Keep looping**

If process x.exe is running > Do action

If process x.exe is not running > Do action

---

The loop should be endless. Every time process x.exe get's started or stopped it should do the action once over and over.

I'm not sure what the right way is to do this.

Using a While loop kills the CPU so that can't be the right move.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Using a While loop kills the CPU"... who told you that?

Comment: My Task manager running the app at 15% CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [ManagementEventWatcher Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementeventwatcher.aspx). It allows you to subscribe to temporary event notifications, like process start.

```
string startEventName = "InstanceCreationEvent";
string stopEventName = "InstanceDeletionEvent";
string processName = "notepad.exe";

ListenForProcess(processName, startEventName, (sender, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Process Started");
});

ListenForProcess(processName, stopEventName, (sender, e) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Process Stopped");
});
```

This function will listen for the events:

```
static void ListenForProcess(string processName,
    string eventName, EventArrivedEventHandler eventHandler)
{
    string queryString =
        $@"SELECT TargetInstance
        FROM __{eventName}
        WITHIN 0.1
        WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'
        AND TargetInstance.Name='{processName}'";

    using (var watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(queryString))
    {
        watcher.EventArrived += eventHandler;
        watcher.Start();

        new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                watcher.WaitForNextEvent();
            }
        }).Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i needed! One thing though. Whenever i run this in my file the file called "WMI Provider Host" ( WmiPrvSE.exe ) will start using a LOT of CPU. I am talking about 50/60% of my i7. If i close my app and run it again it goes even up more untill it reaches 100%.

Comment: In my PC it takes 0% CPU. Try making a new project and paste only this code. Then you can check the resource usage.